# Who should be credited as an author in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Can't find any information about this.
Is it the creator of the project, all contributors who had their code merged or all contributors who have a certain amount of code in the project?

Consider a code base of 500 lines, and the following contributors:

```
name: my_package
description: A Widget that does everything.
authors:
- Creator <creator@gmail.com> #500 lines
- Contributor1 <cont1@gmail.com> #1000 lines
- Contributor2 <cont2@gmail.com> #100 lines
- Contributor3 <cont3@gmail.com> #10 lines
- Contributor4 <cont4@gmail.com> #1 lines

homepage: https://github.com/me/my_package
version: 1.2.0
```

Which contributors belong in authors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's common to have all people who contributed anything listed, even fixes to typos in README or code files, but it's completely up to the project owner.

It's probably a good idea to add a CONTRIBUTING.md file to your project and mention the rules you want to apply to your project. You could also mention that people who are interested include themselves to `authors` in `pubspec.yaml` so you don't need to maintain it yourself.

Comment: Ok, I have rights to publish to dart pub and didn't know if I should add myself and the other contributors.
I guess I should ask him first.